# Can't get Auth object and cookies by consuming my own Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel-5, cookies, proxy, guzzle

I'm currently trying to build a secure SPA application in Laravel by using :

- Laravel 5.6
- Laravel Passport
- Guzzle client

To make the whole application secure, I created a proxy to prefix all requests to the API and :

- User the password grand type of token
- Hide the client ID
- Hide the client secret
- Add automatic scopes based on the role of the user

This is how the Proxy works :

```
// The proxify endpoint for all API requests
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () 
{
    Route::any('proxify/{url?}', function(Request $request, $url) {
        return Proxify::makeRequest($request->method(), $request->all(), $url);
    })->where('url', '(.*)');
});
```

Each time a request is made, it goes through that package I built to create the access token, refreshing it, or deleting it.

To create the access token for the user I'm using a MiddleWare at loggin :

```
$response = $http->post('http://myproject.local/proxify/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type'    => 'password',
                    'username'      => $request->get('email'),
                    'password'      => $request->get('password'),
                ]
            ]);
```

This is working well, excepting the fact that I'm setting cookies in the Proxify::makeRequest, so I have to create them in the call, return them in the $response, and then at the end of the Middleware, attaching them to the request (Cookie::queue and Cookie::Make are not working in a Guzzle call it seems).

The access token is created and stored in a cookie.

First problem is that in this call, even in the middleware, and especially in that URL http://myproject.local/proxify/oauth/token, I don't have any access to the Auth trait, even if it's specified as a middleware attached to the route, so impossible to fetch information from the authenticated user.

Then the other problem is that when I'm making a call to get a ressource API such as :

```
$http = new Client();

$response = $http->get('http://myproject.local/proxify/api/continents');

$continents = $response->getBody()->getContents();

return view('dashboard')->with("continents", $continents);
```

In that case, when I'm calling the URL, the proxy is not able to get the access_token defined in the cookie with the CookieFacade through the HTTP call, neither the Auth object I'm whiling to use. The $_COOKIE variable is not working neither.

What is wrong with my structure so that I don't have any access to the cookie even if it's set and in the browser ? Any other way to get the info ? I tried to get the cookie from the request in the proxy, not working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Illuminate or Symfony Request classes and handling the routing via the Laravel instance? My immediate suspicion is Guzzle is the culprit behind no cookies coming through with the requests. `Cookie::queue()` is a Laravel specific feature so I wouldn't think Guzzle would know anything about them.

Replace Guzzle in one of the routes where the issue occurs. Start with a new Request instance and make the internal api call like:

```
 // create new Illuminate request
$request = Request::create('/api/users', $action, $data, [], [], [
    'Accept' => 'application/json', 
]);

// let the application instance handle the request
$response = app()->handle($request);

// return the Illuminate response with cookies
return $response->withCookies($myCookies);
```

I do something similar to this in a couple applications and never had any problems with cookies or accessing server variables. Granted, it's only for authentication, the rest of the api calls are through axios.